# How do you extract numbers which do not match some pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to extract numbers that are longer than 3 digits and do not include years within a given range (e.g. between `19xx` and `2020`, where `XX` is always in the end of the string).

I am currently using the following pattern:

```
/(?!19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9]|201[0-9]|202[0-9])\d{3,}$/i
```

When I test the expression with *"something 2012"*, I always get the result `012`. I need to get `null`.

```
var s = "moose high performance drive belt 2012";
s.match(/(?!19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9]|201[0-9]|202[0-9])\d{3,}$/i);
```

Why does this expression incorrectly match the end of a date?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't match numbers with greater than three digits first, and then do simple comparisons in a second step?

Comment: I've updated my solution, as the first was flawed.  Do let us know if you're able to simplify it.

Comment: 2 steps is easy enough I guess. I thought it must be possible with pure regex one-liner.

Comment: @mvblfst - you should test it with text such as `ABC 12 DEF 2012 MODEL2000A 34 MODEL78B 123` and see difference between answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It discards `something` , then attempts to match `2012` but fails due to your negative look-ahead assertion, then attempts to match `012`, which *succeeds* because indeed, `012` does not match your negative lookahead assertion.

**UPDATE:**

This isn't pretty but it's one solution.  Perhaps you can simplify it.

```
    (?!(?:19[0-9]{2}|200[0-9]|201[0-9]|202[0-9])\D)(?<!\d)\d{3,}
```

See a demo here: http://rubular.com/r/FLiehrUEp8.

Answer (score 1):

*For years **1900** - **2029** it should be regex* `\b(\d+)\b(?<!(?:19\d{2}|20[0-2]\d))`